# Alignment in ctypes struct field

Tags: python, struct, ctypes, memory-alignment

I have a library with structs like this:

```
#define __aligned_u64 __u64 __attribute__((aligned(8)))

struct my_struct {
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint8_t c[8];
    uint32_t d;
    uint32_t e;
    __aligned_u64 f;
    __aligned_u64 g;
    uint64_t h;
    ...
} __attribute__((aligned(8)));
```

I want to parse it with a ctypes Structure. I think the structure alignment attribute (at the end) is not important for the Python Structure (not to be confused with `packed`).

But I suspect that the alignment of the fields `f` and `g` (the same `__aligned_u64` [used in the Linux kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/include/uapi/linux/types.h#L48)) may mess with the arrangement of the bytes, adding some potential padding after field `e`. I didn't see any option in Structure to define this.

Any ideas? Alternatives? I would like it to be portable...

Comment: PD: I verified that the first fields, such a and b are correct, but I have doubts about the rest...

Comment: Couldn't find the answer, but since fields a + b + c + d + e take 24 bytes, f and g are already aligned to 8 bytes, so no extra alignment is needed.